# How to give the absolute path for html img src?

Tags: java, image, jsp, dynamic, struts2

I'm using Struts2 in my application. I have a HTML `<img>` tag, and for the `src`, I'm using Struts2 property value. Property's value is an image name (coming from database). I tried with this

```
<s:iterator value="items" var="items">                
   <img onerror = "this.style.display='none'" 
            src = 'D:/product_images/<s:property value="image"/>' 
          style = "width: 290px; height: 260px" 
   />
   <s:label label="Imge path" value='D:/product_images/%{image}'/>
 </s:iterator>
```

My Struts label shows a correct path. But when I declared in `src` as a property, the image isn't visible. How to give the path correctly to `img` tag `src` attribute?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you using a local server ? :>

Comment: Yes. Glassfish server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should be configured either on the server or in your application. Like in [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-dynamic-image-example/) example.

```
<img onerror = "this.style.display='none'" 
  src = "<s:url action='ImageAction'><s:param name="imageId" value="%{image}"/></s:url>" 
  style = "width: 290px; height: 260px"/>
```